# Which is the better way to pass additional data for a changed workflow?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, architecture, argument-passing, single-responsibility-principle

Let entity `A` relates to entities `B` and `C` both as 1:1..*
At the same time `B` contains only part of `C`'s key, but together with `A`'s key it is possible to relate `B` to `C`.

Translation to human language:
Accounting Center (A) consists of Branches (C), and a stream of Payments (B) comes to the system from Accounting Center and contains BranchId which is unique only within a given Accounting Center. Wee need to check the correctness of provided BranchId and tie the Payment to the Branch.)

We process the collection of `B`s:

```
class BsProcessor
{
    private BProcessor _processor;

    void ProcessBs(IEnumerable bs)
    {
          for (var b in bs)
          {
              _processor.Process(b);
          }
    }
}
```

One day requirements change, and now `BProcessor` needs to make a decision based on corresponding `C`.

From the view of performance it's better to get in advance all `C`s  for the `A`s which `B`s point to, and then pass this data to BProcessor via changing `Process` method signature.

```
class BsProcessor
{
    private BProcessor _processor;
    private CProvider _provider;

    void ProcessBs(IEnumerable bs)
    {
          var aKeys = bs.Select(b => b.aKey);
          var cs = _provider.GetCsForAs(aKeys).ToDictionary( c => c.aKey);

          for (var b in bs)
          {
              var cCandidates = cs[b.aKey];
              _processor.Process(b, cCandidates);
          }
    }
}
```

`BProcessor` then tries to find the matching `C`.

This is a straightforward fast to code and simple working solution...
To be honest I don't like it wholeheartedly. I think it violates SRP.
There is no any other reason but performance for the `BsProcessor` to be aware of `Cs`.

The logic of finding `C` candidates and matches belongs neither to `BsProcessor` nor to `BProcessor`, but a dedicated service `CMatcher`

```
class CMatcher
{
    private CProvider _provider;
    private IEnumerable<aKey> _aKeys;

    public CMatcher(CProvider provider, IEnumerable<aKey> aKeys)
    {
        ...
    }

    public C Match(aKey akey, cPartialKeyFromB partialKey)
    {
    } 
}
```

This service should be injected and used by `BProcessor`. As this service is contextual and requires collection of aKeys we need to switch to the factory:

```
class BsProcessor
{
    private BProcessorFactory _factory;

    void ProcessBs(IEnumerable bs)
    {
          var aKeys = b.Select(b => b.aKey);
          var processor = _factory.Create(aKeys);
          for (var b in bs)
          {
             processor.Process(b);
          }
    }
}
```

I think this solution is a bit more complex to code, but easier to test.
The only problem I have is that `BProcessor` contains more than one method, and those do not require to match `C` to `B`, hence it is not good to use constructor injection, whereas method injection makes `BsProcessor` know about `CMatcher` what is somewhat similar to initial solution.

Here it starts looking like `BProcessor` begs for being divided into separate classes, and I ask myself whether SRP is worth so much refactoring and where second approach is indeed better than the first one?

Answer (score 1):

The trick, I think, is to take the first approach, but *pass in* the `CProvider` during processing, rather than *containing* the `CProvider` at all times.

Also, depending on what else is involved in processing, you may not need to have `BProcessor`/`BsProcessor` classes at all; simply let each `B` be capable of processing itself, given a `CProvider` to find the corresponding `C` with.

Here's a quick and dirty example, using your accounting analogy above.  Fair warning, I'm not validating much data, and I might be making bad assumptions about the requirements of the structures.

```
// A
class AccountingCenter
{
    private List<Branch> m_branches = new List<Branch>();

    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public ReadOnlyCollection<Branch> Branches { get { return m_branches.AsReadOnly(); } }

    public AccountingCenter(string id, IEnumerable<string> branchIds = null)
    {
        Id = id;
        if (branchIds != null)
        {
            foreach(var b in branchIds)
            {
                AddBranch(b);
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddBranch(string id)
    {
        m_branches.Add(new Branch(id, this));
    }
}

// C
class Branch
{
    private AccountingCenter m_parentCenter;

    public string BranchId { get { return m_parentCenter.Id + "-" + Id; } } // or whatever the combined implementation would be
    public string Id { get; private set; }

    public Branch(string id, AccountingCenter center)
    {
        Id = id;
        m_parentCenter = center;
    }
}

// CProvider
class AccountingCenterContainer
{
    private Dictionary<string, Branch> m_BranchIdToBranchMap = new Dictionary<string, Branch>();

    public AccountingCenterContainer(IEnumerable<AccountingCenter> centers)
    {
        foreach (var c in centers)
        {
            foreach (var b in c.Branches)
            {
                m_BranchIdToBranchMap.Add(b.BranchId, b);
            }
        }
    }

    public Branch GetBranchFromId(string branchId)
    {
        if (!m_BranchIdToBranchMap.ContainsKey(branchId))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("ID " + branchId + " does not correspond to any known branch");
        }
        return m_BranchIdToBranchMap[branchId];
    }
}

// B
class Payment
{
    public string BranchId { get; private set; }

    public Payment(string branchId)
    {
        BranchId = branchId;
    }

    public void Process(AccountingCenterContainer container)
    {
        Branch b = container.GetBranchFromId(BranchId);
        // process...
    }
}
```

Comment: What you offer is a DDD.  I doubt team will readily accept this paradigm shift from transaction script. =( Nonetheless, thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

SRP is just a guidance, and it can be safely violated under concise decision. So if you don't think that the separation does not give direct benefit, it is fine to violate it.

But let's say that you want to separate the responsibility though. I see that your solution isn't optimal.

- First, it still need to know the involvement of aKey during getting the `C` in `CMatcher`. Why don't you pass `IEnumerable<B>` instead?
- Second, you change the `BsProcessor`'s class signature, from originally provide them with `BProcess` now you are generating via a factory. I don't know what the benefit the factory bring, if it is justifiable then go on. But if not, why not use the initial signature? You can: 1. Add `C` property in each of `B` class, which is OO way and introduce coupling, or introduce another class which hold `B` and `C`, and pass the class into the `BProcessor`.

Comment: I thought about passing Bs to factory, but there is another guidance to require the least minimum sufficient for performing the operation.

Comment: Probably, I don't get you right , but the B's key to the C is received from external event which activates the processing of the B. Moreover, B itself is created from this event. Then we need to resolve the corresponding C.

Comment: @voroninp Law of demeter right? See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/284146 for better explanation.

Comment: Honestly I don't get the whole process to get `C` from `B`. Maybe you need to re-describe the process in the question. However taken from the second code block of `BsProcessor`, I think that you don't need to do anything to get `BProcessor` list.